# What Color am I?

Tags: riddle

Everything starts with a hashtag nowadays

First of all, I am number one

I have the letter that you need to count up to a one thousand to able to see me

I also something that sounds like the vast sea

I also have a thing that everybody thinks that is related to something bad when there are three of them

And lastly, I have the command from an online game for surrender

What Color am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything starts with a hashtag nowadays

> # - Precursor to HEX color code

First of all, I am number one

> 1 - Self Explanatory

I have the letter that you need to count up to a one thousand to able to see me

> A - Is the only letter that is unique when you spell out every number from 1 - 1000 (in the spelling of thousand)

I also something that sounds like the vast sea

> C - C sounds like sea (or maybe like waves crashing on the beach?)

I also have a thing that everybody thinks that is related to something bad when there are three of them

> 6 - 666 is considered the devil's mark

And lastly, I have the command from an online game for surrender

> FF - Forfeit command in league.

What Color am I?

> Blue, the HEX color code is #1AC6FF [image]

Comment: can you explain how you got it?

Comment: @Dranier - Edited original post

Answer (score 2):

partial answer

Everything starts with a hashtag nowadays

> #

First of all, I am number one

> 1

I have the letter that you need to count up to a one thousand to able to see me

> "letter a", it comes first in "thousand" (if you spell out the numbers 1-999, "a" never comes)

I also something that sounds like the vast sea

I also have a thing that everybody thinks that is related to something bad when there are three of them

And lastly, I have the command from an online game for surrender

> League of Legends surrender command "ff"

What Color am I?

> something near to blue maybe, it will be clear after finding rest of the clues